# How to say 'It differs depending on the person'

Tags: word-choice, particles, particle-に

Would the following sentence be correct?

人によってちがいます。

Or would it make more sense to use '人々'? As in;

人々によってちがいます。

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence that uses 「人」 would be far more natural than your second with 「人々」.

There is no comparison here.